# Excel match 2 columns get return value

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

***My data:***

[image]

I'm trying to match 2 columns from 2 tables,and then in table 1 return the value from table 2,function i use in output(orange color column) column is `=IF(A:D,E,"")`,but not working,any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VLOOKUP()` `Index, Match` to achieve that. I suggest you to use `Index, Match` formula. See below...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$20,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$20,0)),"")
```

[image]